# Select rows with highest version for a shared key

Tags: sql, mysql

Here's the Schema in mysql:

```
CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `labs_test`.`games` (
  `game_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
  `key` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,
  `config` BLOB NOT NULL ,
  `game_version` BIGINT NOT NULL DEFAULT 1 ,
  PRIMARY KEY (`game_id`) ,
  INDEX `key` (`key`(8) ASC) ,
  INDEX `version` (`game_version` ASC) )
ENGINE = InnoDB
DEFAULT CHARACTER SET = utf8
```

I've tried using MAX(game_version) to no avail. Should I give up the dream and use a sub query?

Comment: Can you show the code where you're trying to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
SELECT g.*
  FROM GAMES g
  JOIN (SELECT t.key,
               MAX(t.game_version) AS max_version
          FROM GAMES t
      GROUP BY t.key) x ON x.key = g.key
                       AND x.max_version = g.game_version
```

### Should I give up the dream and use a sub query?

Some would call what I used in my answer a subquery, but it'd be more accurate to call it a derived table/inline view.  Unless I'm missing something, I don't see how you can get the records without some form of self-join (joining the same table onto itself).  Here's the EXISTS alternative:

```
SELECT g.*
  FROM GAMES g
 WHERE EXISTS(SELECT NULL
                FROM GAMES t
               WHERE t.key = g.key
            GROUP BY t.key
              HAVING MAX(t.game_version) = g.game_verion
```

Use the EXPLAIN plan to determine which performs best, rather than be concerned with whether or not to use a subquery.

Comment: Works perfectly, thank you very much! I'll see which of the two queries works best, but this is exactly what I was looking for.